# How can I write my own Media Framework Extension?

Tags: media-library

I've noticed that Ooyala and Brightcove both have their own media connectors. I'm looking at using a different media provider, and am trying to figure out what the amount of effort would be to write my own provider. Where are the extension points that I can use to create my own login and data retrieval methods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the media framework integration guide will get you what you need.

https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/products/sitecore%20media%20framework/21/sitecore_media_framework_2_1_integration_guide-usletter.pdf

It covers media import, export & synchronization